# Unable to do POST service call with Jar as payload

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am trying to do POST service call with JAR file as payload, I get below error

> no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type
>   [org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap] and content type
>   [application/octet-stream]

Code I tried is below, any help here would be great

```
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("*.jar").getFile());

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader);
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);

    LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> payLoad = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
    payLoad.add("file", new FileSystemResource(file));

    HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>>(payLoad, headers);
    try {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();         

        ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, Object.class);
    } catch (RestClientException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have to add a `HttpMessageConverter` to handle the octet stream. Try adding something like this in your WebConfig

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

    messageConverters.add(new ResourceHttpMessageConverter());

    super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
}
```